# javascript - String to real Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-reference

I have a javascript objects `var flower_1;  var flower_2;`

My question is if I have another variable for example a String `var Name;`

And lets say for example: `Name = "flower_1";`

How can I change the `Name` variable into an object `"flower_1"`

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're asking here. If you can post real code (even if it doesn't quite work), that will improve things a lot. Right now it's hard to even tell what's in the string and what isn't (`====>` is not how you quote strings).

Comment: Try to use eval() although i do not really understand why you would have to do like that. Try another designpattern.

Comment: HEY MAN! this is a really good qustion, only it was a little ugly. PLEASE UPVOTE!

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you have something like this:

```
function foo() {
    var flower_1 = { /* ... */ };
    var flower_2 = { /* ... */ };
    var name = "flower_1";

    var target = /* code here to get the correct object based on `name` */;
}
```

You *can* do that, but it should be avoided if at all possible:

```
var target = eval(name);
```

`eval` is a very big, and easily abused tool which should be, and can be, avoided. I've never had to use it in production code in several years of JavaScript development. Also note that `eval` is disallowed in the new ["strict" mode](http://es5.github.com/#x4.2.2) of the language (one of many improvements strict mode brings).

In this particular case, it's pretty easy to avoid:

```
function foo() {
    var objects = {
        flower_1: { /* ... */ },
        flower_2: { /* ... */ }
    };
    var name = "flower_1";

    var target = objects[name];
}
```

Now, `flower_1` and `flower_2` are *properties* of an object, and you can use bracketed notation (`[]`) with a string name to access those properties. This is because in JavaScript objects, you can either access a property using dotted notation and a literal (e.g., `obj.foo`), or using bracketed notation and a string (e.g., `obj["foo"]`). In the second case, the string doesn't have to be a string literal, it can be the result of an expression, including (as in this case) retrieving the string from a variable.

[Here's a live example of both techniques.](http://jsbin.com/apacox)

Note that if your `var` statements are globals, then those vars become properties of the global object, which on web browsers is `window`, so **if** they're globals you could access them via `window[name]` for exactly the same reason `objects[name]` works. But it's best practice to avoid global variables (entirely if you can, or exposing just one with a good unique name that then contains all of your public stuff if necessary — e.g., if external code needs to access your stuff).

Comment: nice answer. dont forget the eval is deprecated in strinct mode!

Comment: @omnosis: Yes, I should have mentioned that (and now I have). :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval()` function:

```
var flower_1 = "abc";
var name = "flower_1";

var x = eval(name); // = "abc"
```

It's worth noting though that use of the `eval()` function is not best practise, and should be avoided at all costs.

A better (and much more recommended) solution would be to use an associative array:

```
var name = "flower_1";
var arr = new Array();
arr["flower_1"] = "abc";

var x = arr[name]; // = "abc"
```

Comment: Don't use `Array` when you're not using array features. All you need there is an object, `var obj = {}; obj.flower_1 = "abc";` **All** JavaScript objects are maps (aka "associative arrays", but I avoid the term because it's misleading).

Comment: Consider me schooled on javascript objects.